# Golang app-engine performance parameters

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, go

Using stock out-of-the-box configuration on a golang app-engine project, I am getting very disappointing performance.  Any hints on what I might be missing?  How should a golang google app be optimized?

Sending a few dozen requests, not more than six concurrently, I find only one instance handling all the requests, up to six requests concurrently (not sequentially) on that one instance - where I expected to see up to six instances.  Possibly as a result, things seem to be blocking.  I am seeing many timeouts, even on administrative functions like blobstore.Create(), which didn't happen when requests were being sent and processed individually.

EDIT1:  These three lines

```html
context.Infof("Sending request to blobstore to create %s as %s", Name, MimeType)
blobWriter, err := blobstore.Create(context, MimeType)
if err!=nil {
 context.Warningf("Unable to access content store: %v",err)
}
```

are producing:

> ```
> I 12:47:36.201 Sending request to blobstore to create download.jpg as application/octet-stream
> W 12:47:41.251 Unable to access content store: Canceled: Deadline exceeded (timeout)
> ```

On failure here it is always about five seconds in blobstore.Create (a few milliseconds when it passes).  Timeouts also occur in blobstore.Write and blobstore.Close and datastore, but with 20 to 30 second delays.
--End EDIT1.

There also seem to be performance issues.  There is one computationally intensive bit, taking nearly a second to complete on my home machine (at 1.7GHz).  According to the logged time stamps, that same code running on the remote app-engine (at 600MHz) is taking over 30 seconds on average, with a maximum of 109 seconds.  That doesn't seem right!

EDIT2:  The most computationally intensive bit used the resize function:
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/example/moustachio/resize/resize.go
(with the obvious bug fixes).  Not the most efficient resizer, but fast enough for now in a stand-along app.  However it runs an order of magnitude slower in appengine (either the local SDK version 1.9 or running on Google's servers).  Perhaps Google's version of the image library is slower?  Probably the library? - A recursive fibonacci computation runs inside appengine in the same time as outside (same order of magnitude as C code).
--- End EDIT2

Any hints on how to get google app performance more similar to a multi-threaded stand-along application?  So far these preliminary scaling experiments have been a miserable failure!

UPDATE: Using runtime.GOMAXPROCS(6), for a maximum of 6 concurrent requests, made no measurable difference.  When using "manual_scaling" with more instances that requests was helpful, requests usually get assigned to different instances, but sometimes not - leading to problems.

A partial solution:  Segregate computationally intensive requests on a separate module, running on separate instances, so that they do not block smaller more time-sensitive requests.  Next, break down larger functions into several smaller requests, so that several can run "concurrently" on the same instance without timing out?  (Make the client send several requests to do one job!)

It would be much better if I could ask the appengine just to start new instances for each request when none are available.  Experimentally, starting a new instance is much cheaper than running two requests in slow motion on one instance.

Comment: On re-reading the docs I find: "if one request is, say, waiting for a datastore API call, another request may be processed by the same instance." - but that doesn't explain why it sometimes takes 20 seconds to print the log entry on the first line of the request handler.

Comment: Are your test results from a production environment? What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Try setting `GOMAXPROCS` to something other than 1.

Comment: It's hard to comment on performance without knowing what your code is doing, but does this happen only on the loading request or all requests?  Have you tried [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-trace)?

Comment: At a tangent, but perhaps do the resizing outside of your app by using get_serving_url with the desired size appended to the request, instead of doing it your app?

Comment: @tx802  Loading requests run instantly, very little initialization.  The problem is concurrent requests in the same (running) instance.  The internal multi-tasking seems to be failing and requests are blocking each other.  No problem with concurrent requests in different instances (I've tried manually created a huge number of instances so that the odds favour different instances).  I'd like to prevent requests being loaded into instances which are already serving requests - use instances which are not currently serving or, if necessary, automatically create new ones.  How does one set that up?

Comment: @Paul Collingwood  Thanks for the suggestion.  According to the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/images/reference "get_serving_url" is severly limited in the manipulations it will perform.  Although a quick peak at source https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/internal/image/images_service.pb.go suggests greater flexibility is possible... On the other hand, I think I resent the implication that appengine programs cannot do things for themselves, just call google services to do the real work.

Comment: I think it depends. If I expect requests to do significant work immediately I'd be inclined to shuffle them off to a more powerful backend instance with a task queue and return/update when ready, rather than process there and then and eventually return. The CPU etc is configurable - have you tried upping the power of your default instance? At default it's quite low.  I don't see it worthwhile attempting to do computationally intensive things on those low powered instances., at least not very often. Perhaps you want to pass these custom resize tasks off to a Compute VM instance instead?